# Open pop up after clicking android menu item

Tags: android, menu, dialog, popup

I want to open pop up or dialog box after clicking on menu item. I have written the code but the dialog box is not opening. The menu has two items "about" and "help". Is there any other way to show pop up message.?

Here is my code:

```
package com.easy.convert;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class AndroidMenusActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
 * Identify single menu item by it's id
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
 {

switch (item.getItemId())
{
case R.id.menu_help:
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
    dialog.setTitle("Help");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
    return true;

case R.id.menu_about:
    Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
    dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
    dialog1.setTitle("About");
    dialog1.setCancelable(true);
    dialog1.show();
    return true;

default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
} 
}
```

Comment: Your code seems perfect and working on my device.Paste your menu xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     >
    <!-- Single menu item 
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/help"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="Help" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
      android:icon="@drawable/about"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="About" />

    </menu>

Comment: The two menu items (icons) are visible but after clicking on it nothing happens !